# VS2017 C++ compiler error C2664 can not convert argument

Tags: c++, string, unicode, compiler-errors, c2664

Using VS2017 I compile the code below using the *unicode* character set

```
STDMETHODIMP Load(LPCOLESTR lpwszFileName, const AM_MEDIA_TYPE *pmt) {
 TCHAR *szExtension = PathFindExtension(lpwszFileName);
```

and I get the following error

```
error C2664: 'LPSTR PathFindExtensionA(LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'LPCOLESTR' to 'LPCSTR'
```

The same code under VS2008 compiles just fine. What seems to be to problem here and why the compiler chooses the ANSI version of the **PathFindExtenstion** instead of the unicode one ?

Comment: `LPCOLESTR` is always a wide string (UTF-16LE).  You are not building for Unicode so the macro `PathFindExtension` is replaced with `PathFindExtensionA` which expects a narrow string.  Either (a) change the project options to compile for Unicode (recommended) ; (b) Explicitly call `PathFindExtensionW`, or (c) Convert the wide string to a narrow string before making the call.

Comment: I ckecked twice that the character code in the project settings is adjusted to unicode.

Comment: Check `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line` this gives the actual command line being used. Look for `/D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"`  If either or both are missing then the something is wrong elsewhere in the project properties.

Comment: @Richard As soon as I return to my office I will check it out and I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: @Richard you had right. There is no _UNICODE definer in the command line. Take a look below. What parameter inside VS could change the normal behaviour ?

/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"..\..\BaseClasses\" /I"D:\gnosis_v2.00u" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gz /Oy- /MDd /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Async.pch" /diagnostics:classic

Comment: This is for VS2017 (may be in a different place in other versions): `Configuration Properties > General > Project Defaults > Character Set`.  There are 3 options `not set`, `Unicode`, `MBCS`.  `not set` clears the definitions (looks like your config).  `Unicode` adds both Unicode defines and `MBCS` removes Unicode and defines `_MBCS`  You need to [Apply] before checking the compilation string.

Comment: Yes i know this and i confirm that unicode is selected as i noticed in my question. For a reason this selection is not mirrored in the compiler parameters. I repaired my vs2017 just yesterday because it could not find the 8.1sdk. The later is solved and everything else is working fine except that. Of course i can manually add the corresponding parameters directly in the commnd line view but i am really curious to find the root of the problem. Do u think that is maybe a bug ?

Comment: @Maverick Good that you found the root cause, but you shouldn't have ran into this in the first place. Since the input string is not based on `TCHAR`, you shouldn't have been passing it to a `TCHAR`-based API. Like Richard said, just call `PathFindExtensionW` directly and be done with it: `STDMETHODIMP Load(LPCOLESTR lpwszFileName, const AM_MEDIA_TYPE *pmt) { WCHAR *szExtension = PathFindExtensionW(lpwszFileName); ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the VS2017 variable

> %(PreprocessorDefinitions)

was missing from *Preprocessor Definitions*. Now the definers */D _UNICODE* and */D UNICODE* are added correctly to the compiler parameter's list.

[image: The missing the %(PreprocessorDefinitions)]